# Azure Service Fabric end point after container deployment

Tags: azure-service-fabric

This was a container deployment. 
When run locally, it used the machine name: http://joemachine:8229/account/Index. 
"Application URL" property of Service Fabric project is "http://{MachineName}:8229"

After deployment, under All Applications menu, it is showing

fabric:/Application1

Cluster URL: http://abcf12.uksouth.cloudapp.azure.com:19000
end point from Manisfest.xml given below

There is reverse proxy port (19081), and there is a port given in the manifest below. Which port affects the URL?
Also since the machine name is provided in properties, http://{MachineName}:8229, how do I find the machine name of the container
as this is used in the URL?

What is the full URL to access the application?

```
<Resources>
<Endpoints>
  <!-- This endpoint is used by the communication listener to obtain the port on which to
       listen. Please note that if your service is partitioned, this port is shared with
       replicas of different partitions that are placed in your code. -->
  <Endpoint Protocol="http" Name="AST.XyTypeEndpoint" Type="Input" Port="8229" />
</Endpoints>
```

Edit:
In the innermost node in SF explorer, Address->Endpoints, there is a 10.0.0.2:8229 IP given. I tried this, but it's not working.
Also is Node name the machine name? I tried putting that in the URL, and it is not working either.

Comment: did you try `http://abcf12.uksouth.cloudapp.azure.com:8229/account/Index`?

Comment: or with reverse proxy `http://abcf12.uksouth.cloudapp.azure.com:19080/Application1/{your_service_name}/account/Index`. Note: dafault port of reverse proxy is 19081 but not 19080

Comment: @RomanMarusyk, yes tried this '.com:8229/account/Index' doesn't work. will try the other now

Comment: @RomanMarusyk both doesn't work . added an Edit section in question

Comment: What is the service name in your application (Application1) ?

Comment: @RomanMarusyk, i have tried all combinations. exact service name I am not giving here

Comment: @RomanMarusyk Application:ASGApplication , Service:ASGType

Comment: ok, thanks. So, what url did you tried with reverse proxy ?

Comment: 1)http://abcf12.uksouth.cloudapp.azure.com:19081/ASGApplication/ASGType/account/Index 2)with either of the app or service name 3) http://abcf12.uksouth.cloudapp.azure.com:19081/account/Index

Answer (score 0):

partial answer. verified container is working successfully inside.

RDP-ed to node cluster `mstsc /v:abcf12.uksouth.cloudapp.azure.com:3389` admin username+password

command prompt

```
set DOCKER_HOST=localhost:2375
```

(exact same port)
and then
`docker ps --no-trunc`
this will list containers

`docker inspect -f "{{ .NetworkSettings.Networks.nat.IPAddress }}" s1233` where s1223 is the first 4 chars of container id.

this will give the IP. http://IP/account/Index  proved that service is loading.

Question still remains how to expose it to the outside world!